# Read from database without DataGrid in Flex

Tags: sql, apache-flex, datagrid

I'm reading data from an SQL database and send it to my Flex app. My source code in Flex is the follow:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="traffic_signals" url="http://localhost/project/connection.php" resultFormat="e4x"/>

<mx:DataGrid x="251" y="95" dataProvider="{traffic_signals.lastResult..signal}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="source" >
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:Image width="94" height="94"/>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

I would like to dump this information in another type of control instead of `DataGrid`. Is it possible, or the only control to do this is `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AdvancedDataGrid control, but basically is the same of DataGrid, the OLAPDataGrid for BI purposes. 
You can also display the data in chart controls, but I don't know if is it that you're looking for.

Comment: Cool. Thanks to your answer I found some good properties in DataGrid and AdvancedDataGrid controls to do what I want :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting. There's a lot of tutorials on the Internet of modified DataGrids, with filter, PDF/Excel exporting and much more, that may supply your needs.